# Why must we use $\frac{\pi}{2} + A$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2} - A$ for proofs

Tags: trigonometry

I want to derive $\sin(A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B$ from $\cos(A-B)=\cos A \cos B +\sin A \sin B$

$$\cos(A-B)=\cos A \cos B +\sin A \sin B$$ substitute $A$ for $A + \frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\cos(A+\frac{\pi}{2}-B)=\cos( A+\frac{\pi}{2}) \cos B +\sin( A+\frac{\pi}{2}) \sin B$$
$$\sin(A-B)=\sin(A) \cos B +\cos(A) \sin B$$

but this is wrong. However you get the correct answer with $\frac{\pi}{2} - A$.
Why?

Comment: Note $\cos(A+\pi) = -\cos(A)$ not $\sin(A)$.  Perhaps you should try $A-\pi/2$ or something, so that you can use $\cos(A-\pi/2) = \sin(A)$.

Comment: In light of this comment, I wonder if the heading needs to be changed.

Comment: I'm curious how the substitution of $\pi-A$ led to the "correct" answer. I'm assuming the working is a chock full of errors as the working in this question, but I haven't guessed yet how the desired formula falls out of it. There must be errors that I haven't even imagined.

Comment: You really need to study up on what happens when you add $\pi$ to the angle in a sine or cosine function or when you subtract the angle from $\pi$. It's nothing like you seem to think. Then you need to study up on how to convert sine to cosine or vice versa by subtracting the angle from $\frac\pi2$. Trig will be much easier if you know correct formulas and don't use incorrect formulas.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It should have been $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos{(A+\pi-B)}=\cos{(A-B+\pi)}=\cos{(A-B)}\cos{\pi}-\sin{(A-B)}\sin{\pi}$
$\cos{(A+\pi-B)}=-\cos{(A-B)}$
Which is not what you were wanting to show, so we need to try something slightly different.

As mentioned in the comments, try the following instead:

$\cos{(A-B-\frac{\pi}{2})}$
$=\cos{(A-B)}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\sin{(A-B)}\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$
$=\cos{(A-B)}\times 0+\sin{(A-B)}\times 1$
$=\sin{(A-B)}$

Now, re-working the way you did above:

$\cos{(A-\frac{\pi}{2}-B)}=\cos{(A-\frac{\pi}{2})}\cos{B}+\sin{(A-\frac{\pi}{2})}\sin{B}$
$=(\cos{A}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\sin{A}\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}})\times\cos{B}+(\sin{A}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\cos{A}\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}})\times\sin{B}$
$=\sin{A}\cos{B}-\cos{A}\sin{B}$

As required.

Comment: That is an error by me - thanks, will edit.